# Как назначить выполнения скрипта при загрузке файлов из интернета?

Tags: python, скрипт, download

Хочу написать скрипт, который при загрузке файла из интернета определял бы его расширение и уже дальше перемещал файл по одному из предустановленных путей. Вопрос заключается в том, как назначить этот скрипт на выполнение, а также получить информацию о самом скачиваемом файле?

Comment: А качает кто и чем?

Comment: @eri пользователь из браузера

Comment: На баше есть команда file которая распознает что за содержимое в файле и есть команда inotify которая следит за появлением новых файлов. На питоне посмотри аналоги. Формат файла можно попробовать распознать через mime ещё